# How do we know if a pointer was allocated with new or new[]?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a unique_ptr class in C++, but how to know if the pointer we passed to it was allocated with `new` or `new[]` without using `default_delete` (my school standard doesn't allow c++11).
I mean when you pass your pointer to the constructor like this for example:

```
unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int[10]);
```

how do you know inside of the class if you need to call `delete[]` or `delete` ?

Comment: Try using a smart unique_ptr for an array instead: `unique_ptr<int[]> ptr(new int[10]);`

Comment: I tried but it din't compile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't tell. And neither can `std::unique_ptr`.

Think about it. If it could be determined automatically, you wouldn't need two kinds of `delete`.

`std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int[10]);` is wrong, since it will call `delete`, rather than `delete[]`.

Use `std::unique_ptr<int[]> ptr(new int[10]);` instead, which will call `delete[]`, rather than `delete`.

Comment: Okay, so is there smart_ptrs for arrays?

Comment: `unique_ptr<type[]>` see also googling "unique_ptr for array"